# Implement Spring Cloud Sleuth's TracingWebFillter in Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a Spring Boot Reactive  application using Functional Endpoints ( Kotlin) that uses Spring Cloud Sleuth. I want to customize the response headers to include the trace id. I looked at the manual and saw the section on using the TraceFilter : [1](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.0.0.M5/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_tracefilter)

I tried to do the same using a TraceWebFilter, but it doesn't expose the constructors. Is there a way to implement this customization when using the Reactive Web Framework.

I am using version 2.0.0.M5 for Spring Cloud Sleuth

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the latest `master` - we've migrated to Brave. You can write your `WebFilter` that will delegate to `TraceWebFilter`. Or you can just copy our `TraceWebFilter` and alter it in the way you need to.